# Django: Use 2nd argument given by url

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a Django website where I can upload series with seasons and episodes. In the end it should look something like this:

Seasons:

```
[1] [2] [3]
```

Episodes:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]
```

The Episodes belong to the season given by the url.

My code looks like this:

**models.py:**

```
class Serie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=serie_dir_path)
    ...


class Season(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    episode = models.FileField(upload_to=episode_dir_path)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**views.py:**

```
class SeriesDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Serie

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SeriesDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'seasons': Season.objects.all(),
            'episodes': Episode.objects.all()
        })
        return context
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('library', LibListView.as_view(), name='library'),
    path('series/<int:pk>/season/<int:order>', SeriesDetailView.as_view(), name='serie-detail'),
]
```

**lib.html:**

```
<a href="{% url 'serie-detail' serie.id 1 %}">
```

(The 1 is because I want the first season)

**serie_detail.html:**

```
<section class="section mt-5">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ serie.title }}</h1>
        <img class="card-img-top mb-2" src="{{ serie.thumbnail.url }}" style="height: 319px; width: 220px;">
        <h6>Uploaded by: <h6 class="category text-warning"> {{serie.createdUser.username}}</h6></h6>
            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="mb-0">Seasons:</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            {% for season in serie.season_set.all %}
                <a href="" class="btn btn-default float-left">{{ season.order }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="mb-0">Episodes:</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            {% for season in serie.season_set.all %}
                {% for episode in season.episode_set.all %}
                    <a href="{% url 'episode-detail' episode.id %}" class="btn btn-default float-left btn-sm">{{ episode.order }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

With the code above the result looks like this:

Seasons:

```
[1] [2]
```

Episodes:

```
[1] [1]
```

It takes the first episode of the 2nd season and also shows that.

I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: I see you're not using the context from your view, since you're fetching the related seasons and episodes directly in your template. Your last double for-loop loops through all seasons **and** episodes for each season, so of course you'll see the list of all the episodes of all the seasons. If you want to use the `order` from the url, you should loop through `episodes` (from the context) rather than through `serie.season_set.all` and then `season.episode_set.all`.

Comment: Ok i now first looped through episodes and after that through season.episode_set.all. But the problem is that now it doesn't show a episode at all. Sorry if i'm a bit stupid but i'm not that long into django

Comment: `{% for episode in episodes %} {{ episode.title }} {% endfor %}` will show you all the titles for the episodes in your context. In your context you should set the `episodes` to just the ones for the specific season as mentioned in the answer below with my correction (`self.kwargs...`). There shouldn't be a double for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need to display all the seasons episodes of only one particular season (season 1 in this case). You would need to modify the code something like below:

```
class SeriesDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Serie

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        order = kwargs.get("order")
        context = super(SeriesDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'seasons': Season.objects.all(),
            'episodes': Episode.objects.filter(season=order)
        })
        return context
```

Comment: Yes but if I change the url to: serie/1/season/2 it should show the episodes of season two.

Comment: that's what `filter(season=order)` does, it filters for the episodes of season <order>. But since `order` is the `id` of the season, it should probably be `.filter(season_id=order)`. Also the seasons should be filtered, since they should be the ones related to the current series: `Season.objects.filter(serie=self.object)`

Comment: ok i tried it but now it shows an error saying that order is not defined.

Comment: replace `order = kwargs.get('order')` by `order = self.kwargs.get('order')`. But your error says you didn't add that line at all.